# Spring MVC register ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC REST Web Servcie project. How do I register my implementation class for ContainerResponseFilter?  I added @Provider but  there is something else missing. I am not using a web.xml file but using an ApplicationConfiguration class. I have proven that my  implementation class is not been called.

@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter  {